# App Crashes when Button is clicked (Passing a string between two classes.)

Tags: java, android, string, crash, bundle

I've started on another class that get's two strings from another class, I've only set up one so far, but I just tested it out, but when I fill in my two edit text's and hit submit it crashes.

First Class (Launcher Class)

```
package com.gta5news.bananaphone;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import android.R.string;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

 public class LogIn extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
Button send;
EditText user;
EditText pass;
CheckBox staySignedIn;
FileOutputStream Fos;
String FILENAME = "userandpass";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);
    send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bLogIn);
    user = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eTuser);
    pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eTpassword);
    staySignedIn = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.Cbstay);
    send.setOnClickListener(this);
    try {
        Fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Fos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (staySignedIn.isChecked()) {

        String a = user.getText().toString();
        String b = pass.getText().toString();
        File f = new File(FILENAME);
        try {
            Fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
            //Write some Data
            Fos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 


    } 

}

public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.bLogIn:
        if (pass.length() == 0)
            Toast.makeText(this,
                    "Try to type in your username and password again!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        else if (user.length() == 0)
            Toast.makeText(this,
                    "Try to type in your username and password again!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        else {

            String u = user.getText().toString();
            String p = pass.getText().toString();
            Bundle send = new Bundle();
            send.putString("key", u);
            send.putString("key", p);
            Intent a = new Intent(LogIn.this, logincheck.class);
            startActivity(a);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Were signing you in!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
            break;
        }
    }

}
}
```

Second Class:

```
package com.gta5news.bananaphone;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class logincheck extends Activity {
String GotBread;
TextView user;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.logincheck);
    user = (TextView) findViewById(R.layout.logincheck);
    SetUp();

}

public void SetUp() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Bundle GotData = getIntent().getExtras();
    GotBread = GotData.getString("key");
    user.setText(GotBread); {


}

}
}
```

LogCat:

```
01-19 08:53:56.641: E/AndroidRuntime(3319):     ... 11 more
01-19 08:56:28.561: E/AndroidRuntime(3384): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-19 08:56:28.561: E/AndroidRuntime(3384): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start  activity ComponentInfo{com.gta5news.bananaphone/com.gta5news.bananaphone.logincheck}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-19 08:56:28.561: E/AndroidRuntime(3384):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
01-19 08:56:28.561: E/AndroidRuntime(3384):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
01-19 08:56:28.561: E/AndroidRuntime(3384):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
01-19 08:56:28.561: E/AndroidRuntime(3384):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
01-19 08:56:28.561: E/AndroidRuntime(3384):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-19 08:56:28.561: E/AndroidRuntime(3384):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-19 08:56:28.561: E/AndroidRuntime(3384):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
01-19 08:56:28.561: E/AndroidRuntime(3384):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-19 08:56:28.561: E/AndroidRuntime(3384):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
 01-19 08:56:28.561: E/AndroidRuntime(3384):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
01-19 08:56:28.561: E/AndroidRuntime(3384):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
01-19 08:56:28.561: E/AndroidRuntime(3384):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-19 08:56:28.561: E/AndroidRuntime(3384): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-19 08:56:28.561: E/AndroidRuntime(3384):     at com.gta5news.bananaphone.logincheck.SetUp(logincheck.java:24)
01-19 08:56:28.561: E/AndroidRuntime(3384):     at com.gta5news.bananaphone.logincheck.onCreate(logincheck.java:17)
01-19 08:56:28.561: E/AndroidRuntime(3384):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-19 08:56:28.561: E/AndroidRuntime(3384):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
01-19 08:56:28.561: E/AndroidRuntime(3384):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: What exception is being thrown?

Comment: Could you post the exception from your logcat?

Comment: Sure! http://pastebin.com/RTE8jZXS

Comment: For some reason, your extras Bundle is null. Make all these changes we suggested and update the thread with your new code and the new exception.

Comment: what happen ,Are change your code and logcat...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Get Bundle in Oncreate Method**

**And**

Use Like

```
Intent i = new Intent(Login.this,logincheck.class);
i.putExtra("key", user);
i.putExtra("key1", pass);
startActivity(i);
```

And

```
 user = (TextView) findViewById(R.layout.logincheck);
```

**Instead of**

```
user = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.logincheck);
```

**So User is Null**

Answer (score 0):

On your main activity you're creating the Bundle and inserting the content in it, but you're not sending it to the the intent.

You should put the information on the Intent before starting the second activity. Do something like this:

```
    Intent a = new Intent(LogIn.this, logincheck.class);
    a.putExtra("key", u);
    a.putExtra("key", p);
    startActivity(a);
```

Comment: You're getting the same exception?

Answer (score 0):

I will try to give u a clue how to solve it..it can be even more fail-proffed but this should work for u..

```
Intent i = new Intent(LogIn.this, logincheck.class); 
i.putExtra("username", sUsername);
i.putExtra("password", SPassword);
```

To get the saved data in new activity try with:

```
String newString;
if(extras == null) {
        sUsernameInNewActivity = null;
        sPasswordInNewActivity = null;
} else {
        sUsernameInNewActivity = extras.getString("username");
        sPasswordInNewActivity = extras.getString("password");
}
```

btw. A lot of bad practice in your code.. :( I have troubles to read it easy..
for example:

- you have two variables with different scope and type but exactly the same name (try to find it)
- did u want to join something with this code or???

  send.putString("key", u);
  send.putString("key", p);

how u thought to get them later? together/separately?

Hope u will solve it. Cheers

Comment: Can u please point to my syntax errors..?
there is typo in sPassword (first letter shouldn't be capital) but what other problems do u have with it?